# pcap files for simulated attacks on SCADA systems?

Tags: snort

I need to get hold of some pcap files belonging to a simulated attack on SCADA systems. My goal is to then use Snort for the detection. Or if somebody can suggest a practical environment to create my own (there is time pressure), that would also be appreciated greatly.

Does anybody have any files at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want pcaps from scada traffic you can go to http://www.netresec.com/?page=PCAP4SICS. On the other hand, if you want to simulate a specific attack probably the best option is to use scapy to generate the (modbus, mqtt, coap or whatever) traffic yourself.